# How to dynamically customize the crop of aviary in Android?

Tags: android, aviary

my previous post :
[How to dynamically customize the crop of aviary in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41428361/how-to-cutom-dynamically-the-crop-of-aviary-in-android-app)

I found some code to customize crop of aviary on override values.xml

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="aviary_crop_labels">
        <item>"Crop"</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="aviary_crop_values">
        <item>1:1</item>
    </string-array>
    <integer name="aviary_crop_selected_index">0</integer>
</resources>
```

how do i change these values dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to do this when I used Aviary(now changed to Creative SDK) and really cannot if you don't modify source code of Aviary. Because Aviary is opened source , you can do this by modifying source code of Aviary (quite easy to do this).
Aviary/CreativeSDK only reads crop options from static values from your xml codes above.

Now, I changed to CreativeSDK and cannot modify crop option at run time. :(

Comment: i don't really understant, 
in aviary it's possible but not in CreativeSDK, is it that?

Comment: You need to modify source code of Aviary to do this because Aviary is opened source, but Aviary is old, now Aviary changed to Creative SDK

Comment: Correct. I suggest you upgrade to CreativeSDK, it supports better with new Android version.

Comment: But there one thing that i don't understand, CreativSDK let iOS the possibility to do this but not Android? It's weird